# Restarting a 2-node elasticsearch cluster with zero downtime

Tags: elasticsearch

We've been running a 2-node ES cluster (now on **1.4.1**) with all defaults and the following overrides:

```
config.cluster.name = "..."
config.discovery.zen.ping_timeout = "5s";
config.discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled = false;
config.discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts = ["IP1", "IP2"];
```

Recently, we've started to notice that when we shut down each node via a `http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cluster/nodes/_local/_shutdown` request, the cluster becomes unresponsive for **30 seconds**.

When the master node is explicitly shutdown, the other node doesn't seem to immediately resume the role of master... instead it keeps trying until the 30 second (default `discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout`) timeout elapses.

During this period, the cluster has a 'no master' block and returns a 503 to the root node request:

```
{
"status" : 503,
"name" : "...",
"cluster_name" : "...",
"version" : {
"number" : "1.4.1",
"build_hash" : "89d3241d670db65f994242c8e8383b169779e2d4",
"build_timestamp" : "2014-11-26T15:49:29Z",
"build_snapshot" : false,
"lucene_version" : "4.10.2"
},
"tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

The block levels are ["write", "metadata"].

You can see this play out in the logs:

```
[2014-12-04 17:46:16,000][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [NODE_1] master_left [[NODE_0][VXtqWIw2Q2C9b5UHvWlZyQ][RD000D3A1024B8][inet[/100.72.14.37:9300]]], reason [shut_down]
[2014-12-04 17:46:16,012][WARN ][discovery.zen            ] [NODE_1] master left (reason = shut_down), current nodes: {[NODE_1][WoVynRBhQvSwvxNp1nj8kw][RD000D3A109006][inet[/100.78.140.38:9300]],}
[2014-12-04 17:46:16,012][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [NODE_1] removed {[NODE_0][VXtqWIw2Q2C9b5UHvWlZyQ][RD000D3A1024B8][inet[/100.72.14.37:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-master_failed ([NODE_0][VXtqWIw2Q2C9b5UHvWlZyQ][RD000D3A1024B8][inet[/100.72.14.37:9300]])
[2014-12-04 17:46:16,497][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:18,358][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:19,508][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:20,384][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:21,150][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:21,915][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:22,540][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:23,384][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:23,900][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:24,572][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:26,794][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:27,783][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:28,441][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:29,330][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:30,393][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:31,264][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:31,905][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:32,608][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:35,572][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:36,529][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:37,295][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:37,911][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:38,661][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:39,411][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:40,032][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:40,643][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:41,505][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:41,927][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:42,630][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:43,380][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:44,193][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:44,963][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:45,824][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:46,511][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:46,574][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:47,278][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:48,028][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:48,373][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:48,811][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:49,530][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:49,530][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:50,155][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:50,405][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:51,030][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:51,170][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:51,889][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:51,938][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:52,530][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:52,561][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:53,406][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:53,596][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:53,908][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:54,353][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:54,587][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:55,056][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:55,712][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:56,322][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:56,806][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:56,962][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:57,791][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:57,806][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:58,228][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:58,447][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:59,088][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:46:59,355][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:46:59,775][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:47:00,400][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] observer: timeout notification from cluster service. timeout setting [30s], time since start [30s]
[2014-12-04 17:47:00,400][DEBUG][action.admin.cluster.state] [NODE_1] no known master node, scheduling a retry
[2014-12-04 17:47:00,619][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [NODE_1] new_master [NODE_1][WoVynRBhQvSwvxNp1nj8kw][RD000D3A109006][inet[/100.78.140.38:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
```

How do we force the current node to give up its role as master during the shutdown command so that the other node can resume this responsibility immediately and prevent the 30-second no master block outage? We've experimented with various 'transient' cluster update calls to force an immediate election to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `discovery.zen.rejoin_on_master_gone` to `false` in your settings file.
This value is `true` by default, meaning that the node will restart the cluster join process when the master leaves instead of electing a master.  If you set it to `false`, the node will elect itself master as soon as it notices the old master has left (assuming your `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes` setting isn't at 2).

Edited to add a caveat:  This setting was added in Elasticsearch 1.4 as part of their fixes to help prevent split brains.  If your cluster was prone to these (or is seeing them again), you'll want to leave this settings as-is.

Comment: I don't understand why this option among many others aren't documented.